# Who loves Unity interface over Gnome?

Tags: unity, gnome

I recently upgraded to unity interface as part of upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04. I liked everything in the new ubuntu version except the unity interface. Even after spending 3-4 full days with Unity what I can say is I did not like it at all. I hate to downgrade/switch to gnome since I feel I am not supporting unity and the philosophy of using always the best.

This is what I found about Unity:

- its fancy but not does not add any
  value ( at its current state )
- harder to perform the operations compared to
  gnome
- very less customizable (more
  like its forced on me, can not change
  much)
- global ( shared ) menus are bad
  for mouse users since mouse has to
  travel long distances

Am I missing anything ? Is the unity in 11.04 is very limited and has great plans in future ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it for a week or two. It's different, but there are some real advantages:
1. Great if you have a widescreen laptop. The launcher on the side frees vertical space.
2. The top panel integration with apps is efficient and attractive.
3. I like that it has a unique interface, not so "Windows" in appearance.

Comment: +1 I have a 16:9 monitor and always used AWN on the side. So its the most natural place for me to have the launcher anyway.. only a shame for some that you can't change its position.

Answer (score 0):

yes
from the very first day of alpha version i loved new unity and still love it. As said above, so much more free space on the screen with it. instead of 4 panels in gnome 2.3 (bottom panel with tasks manager, top one with menu and notification area, windows title and file-edit menu) we have one tiny panel on top. very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Except from some annoyance with compiz and some stuffs. I really do like unity and where it is going. Since it is still very early lets hope it will be polished when we get to 12.04. I love how it gives more space to my laptop and looks very slick.

I would also like some additional features such as:

- Gnome Shell like chat popup
- appmenu/global-menu on maximized mode option

Answer (score 0):

Its not perfect, I don't love it. But as with all things change is inevitable and threatening, it takes us out of our comfort zone.

I reverted to Classic after 2 or 3 days, then I started to feel that I hadn't learnt enough about it AND I read that classic would not be offerred with 11:10.

So now I've been with Unity a few weeks. I'm comfortable with it.

It needs to resolve some dual screen issues, some accessibility issues and some flexibility issues. Unity is neither complete or polished. Coming from Windows (or Mac) that is a bit of a shock, but it will improve and even now it is completely usable. i look forward to more improvements.

I won't be going back